# Rails+MongoDB: "No such file to load"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

New to MongoDB and trying to get a *second* test project working. I emphasize *second* because I'm wondering if that may be part of the problem as in `/data/db/` i still have the files for the first proof-of-concept MongoDB <- MongoID -> Rails project that I got up and running without a problem a few weeks ago.

Now I'm experimenting with building a *new* Rails project from scratch with some flags (`-T -O -J`) and then running the associated install/config generators: `mongoid:config, rspec:install, jquery:install`.

So far so good... until I generate my first scaffold and then try to access it and get the response:

`"No such file to load -- vendor"`

now, I'm not too surprised as there's no new `xxx_development.x` files in `/data/db/`. But I don't remember creating them the first time and tutorials I've been using don't mention such a step? Early onset senility? Or is something amiss? Perhaps MongoDB (or MongoID) can only handle one MongoDB per db directory?!?

```
#Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'mongoid', '2.0.0.rc.7'
gem 'bson_ext'
...
```

Using default `mongoid.yml`.

*I've searched S.O. for related problems and there were many but most either have problems loading a gem, which is not my case, or state that the `bson_ext` version must match the `mongoid` version.. but most of these cases seem old and now I don't even think that's possible with `mongoid` approaching `2.0` and `bson_ext` still at `1.2`.*

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by building another test app from scratch. there seems to be a bug (or my lack of understanding) somewhere perhaps involved with the `-J` flag to `rails new` (or with the combo of using the `-J`, `-T` & `-O` flags at same time?). Anyway, it uncomments the following line in `application.rb`:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w()
```

which should read:

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w(jquery rails)
```

adding "`jquery rails`" made the app work... not sure what the resource name had to do with the original error message!?! Red Herring?